# sending media data over the WebSocket in Play framework

Tags: scala, sockets, playframework, websocket, akka

I am using **akka** based **Websockets** in **Play 2.5.4** and **Scala** , similar in this way :

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.streams._

class Controller4 @Inject() (implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: Materializer) {
  import akka.actor._

  class MyWebSocketActor(out: ActorRef) extends Actor {
    import play.api.libs.json.JsValue
    def receive = {
      case msg: JsValue =>
        out ! msg
    }
  }

  object MyWebSocketActor {
    def props(out: ActorRef) = Props(new MyWebSocketActor(out))
  }

  def socket = WebSocket.accept[JsValue, JsValue] { request =>
    ActorFlow.actorRef(out => MyWebSocketActor.props(out))
  }

}
```

Refer https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWebSockets

My question is If i want to send **media data** over the socket connection (like videos , audio, files,etc.) How would i be able to achieve that? I am sorry if it feels pretty basic or easy to you , but i have no clear idea about this.
Thanks in Advance.